# Server Hardware slower than Workstation Hardware (Same Software)

Tags: windows, performance, sql, multi-threaded

I made my Database Sync. Software multi-threaded. On my own workstation

- CPU : i5 2500
- RAM : 8 GB
- HDD : 2x WDC WD5003ABYZ (Software Mirror)
- OS : Windows 10 Ultimate
- SQL Server : SQL 2008r2

it completes in 0:18-0:25 seconds.

On the server the same thing takes 1 minute and 24 seconds if I am lucky!

- CPU : 2x Intel Xeon E5620
- RAM : 24 GB
- HDD : RAID 6 Toshiba MBF2600RC 500 GB (10K)
- OS : Windows 2008r2
- SQL Server : SQL 2008r2

Both computers are fully updated, and both computers are used only by me. I have no idea what could be causing this, or where should I look.
The software (except the OS) is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your server has less memory bandwidth and a slower CPU than your workstation (though neither is by much).  Database software is almost always either memory or I/O bound, so that's going to hurt it _a lot_.

Comment: Database server configuration is complicated stuff, and a lot of it is focused on how the hardware present is used. the same configuration won't be appropriate on both systems.

Comment: You say "*it completes in 0:18-0:25 seconds*". I ask what is it that is completing in this time frame? There could be a bottleneck in the network or some hop, etc. too from one versus the other. For example, if you are running a query on the workstation and it is closer to the database than the server or has more throughput, etc. then perhaps that's the reason why. I would think the RAID 6 of the 10K drives would be faster than the two WD HDD's so perhaps your bottle neck is the network and depending on what it is doing exactly the WS is physically closer to the data or on faster network gear.

Comment: Where are the devices located?  Could the issue be network bandwidth?

Comment: Hello Everyone, thank you for the fast response, meanwhile I realized that this question is somewhat hard to answer ... sorry.

1. The Server itself is the MSSQL Server 
2. The Application is running on the Server
3. The Server does fetch data from another server but this server itself is on the Same Switch .

I realized that I might be able to narrow down the problem perhaps with VMWARE, right now I am installing a Windows 10 VM with same specs , and I will compare it against the Windows 2008 r2 ... I will update this later.

Thank you again .

Answer (score -1):

Raid6 might be causing some of your issues. Switch to raid 10 if you can and see if it improves. http://wintelguy.com/raidperf.pl shows a ~15% performance decrease with raid6 over raid1. Raid 10 should be considerably faster. There are also use cases where raid6 has a more noticeable effect. https://blog.storagecraft.com/raid-performance/

Don't rule out hardware fault, that server is pretty old I would run a memtest and see if you have issues. Perhaps a hard drive is failing I would check SMART logs. Operating Systems have been optimized over the years, so there's a chance that has some play into it too.